# How to debug an issue in meal generator

Tags: c++, class, random, conditional-statements

I have a meal generator that generates meals for 4 days of the week. There are some meals that I want to count as 2 meals because they produce leftovers. I also have some of the meals in groups (pesto, spaghetti, and tortellini are pasta) which I do not want to appear together in the output. If no pasta meals are selected, 4 meals should show up in the output. If one pasta meal appears in the output, then there should be 3 meals total: the pasta meal, and 2 non pasta meals. That means that a pasta meal cannot be selected as the 4th meal ever.

My code is split into 3 files:
main.cpp

```
#include "include\mealSelector.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> meals = {
        "Spaghetti", "Pesto", "Frozen Pizza", "Nachos", "Potato Skins",
        "Quesadillas", "Hoagies", "Lunch meat sandwiches", "Brats",
        "Chicken, Potatoes and Broccoli", "Taquitos and Mini Corn dogs",
        "App Night", "Grilled Cheese", "Mac & Cheese", "Tortellini"
    };

    MealSelector mealSelector(meals);
    mealSelector.shuffleMeals();
    mealSelector.selectMeals();

    return 0;
}
```

mealSelector.cpp

```
#include "include/MealSelector.h"
#include <algorithm>

MealSelector::MealSelector(const std::vector<std::string>& initialMeals)
    : meals(initialMeals), mealCount(0), pastaAllowed(true) {} // Initialize [Meal Group]Allowed here

void MealSelector::shuffleMeals() {
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::seed_seq ss{ rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd() };
    std::mt19937 mt{ ss };
    std::shuffle(meals.begin(), meals.end(), mt);
}

void MealSelector::selectMeals() {
    for (const auto& meal : meals) {
        if (mealCount >= 4) {
            break; // Exit the loop once we have 4 meals
        }

        if (canSelectPastaMeal(meal) && ((mealCount < 3) || (mealCount == 3 && pastaAllowed))) {
            handleSelectedPastaMeal(meal);
        } else {
            handleRegularMeal(meal);
        }
    }
}

void MealSelector::printAndAddMeal(const std::string& meal) {
    std::cout << meal << std::endl;
    chosenMeals.insert(meal);
}

bool MealSelector::isPastaMeal(const std::string& meal) {
    return (meal == "Pesto" || meal == "Spaghetti" || meal == "Tortellini");
}

bool MealSelector::canSelectPastaMeal(const std::string& meal) {
    if (isPastaMeal(meal)) {
        if (!pastaAllowed || mealCount >= 3) {
            return false; // Disallow selecting more pasta meals if one is already selected
        }

        for (const auto& selectedMeal : lastPastaSelections) {
            if (mealCount - selectedMeal.second < 3 && meal != selectedMeal.first) {
                return false; // Check conditions for pasta meal selection
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void MealSelector::handleSelectedPastaMeal(const std::string& meal) {
    if (mealCount >= 4 || !pastaAllowed) {
        return; //Exit if already selected 4 meals or if pasta is not allowed
    }

    //Check if the pasta meal is allowed based on previous selections
    if (isPastaMeal(meal) && lastPastaSelections.find(meal) != lastPastaSelections.end()) {
        return; // Exit if this pasta meal was already chosen
    }

    // Ensure mutual exclusion among pasta meals
    for (const auto& pasta : {"Spaghetti", "Tortellini", "Pesto"}) {
        if (pasta != meal && lastPastaSelections.find(pasta) != lastPastaSelections.end()) {
            return; // Exit if another pasta meal was already chosen
        }
    }

    printAndAddMeal(meal);
    mealCount += (isPastaMeal(meal)) ? 2 : 1; // Pasta meals count as 2 meals

    if (isPastaMeal(meal)) {
        pastaAllowed = false; // Set pastaAllowed to false after selecting one pasta meal
        lastPastaSelections[meal] = mealCount;
    }
}

void MealSelector::handleRegularMeal(const std::string& meal) {
    if (!isPastaMeal(meal) && mealCount == 3) {
        pastaAllowed = false;
    }
    printAndAddMeal(meal);
    mealCount++;
}
```

mealSelector.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

class MealSelector {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> meals;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> chosenMeals;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> lastPastaSelections; // Track last selection for each pasta meal
    int mealCount;
    bool pastaAllowed;

public:
    MealSelector(const std::vector<std::string>& initialMeals);

    void shuffleMeals();
    void selectMeals();

private:
    void printAndAddMeal(const std::string& meal);
    bool isPastaMeal(const std::string& meal);
    bool canSelectPastaMeal(const std::string& meal);

    void handleSelectedPastaMeal(const std::string& meal);
    void handleRegularMeal(const std::string& meal);
};
```

When I run my code, sometimes it outputs something like this:

```
Tortellini
Spaghetti
Grilled Cheese
```

This:

```
Potato Skins
Lunch meat sandwiches
Mac & Cheese
Tortellini
```

Or This:

```
Spaghetti
Tortellini
Pesto
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Evil code:  please differentiate types, variable and function names by more than case.  For example `MealSelection` vs. `mealSelection`.  Very easy to make typo mistakes when reading the code.

Comment: Since your meal names can have embedded spaces, I highly recommend placing the names between double quotes, ex.: `"Grilled Cheese", "Mac & Cheese"`.

Comment: IMHO, your meals should be more than as string.  You should have a base class and add a virtual function, `virtual bool Contains_Pasta() const = 0;`  You could have a `Pasta_Meal` class that inherits from base `Meal` class and returns `true` for `Contains_Pasta` method.  Thus "Mac_And_Cheese` would be instantiated from `Pasta_Meal`.  Maybe a more generic design is to have all meal classes implement a `Contains(const std::string& ingredient)` method.

Comment: I recommend not placing paths in `#include` statements.  Files move (especially when they are reused).  Instead, tell the compiler where to search for them.

Comment: By your coded logic, `handleRegularMeal` will **always** add whatever meal it is considering, regardless of whether or not it's permitted.  (i.e. even if pasta is not allowed and it's pasta).  You'll need to have a `return` somewhere in `handleRegularMeal` to skip over a pasta meal that is disallowed.

Comment: The answer to "how do I debug this" may very well be to temporarily **remove the random shuffle** and pre-arrange the items into an order that constitutes a failing test case, so that you can debug the same test case over and over a few times until you find and understand the logic error.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving the properties or attributes to the meals:

```
    class Meal
    {
        std::string    m_title;
        unsigned int   m_serves_count;  
        std::string    m_primary_ingredient;
      public:  
        Meal(const std::string& title) : m_title(title)
            { ; }  
        bool contains_ingredient(const std::string& ingredient_title) const  
            { return m_primary_ingredient == ingredient_title; }
        unsigned int get_serving_count() const 
            { return m_serves_count; }  
};
```

You could have `std::vector<Meal> weekly_meals;`.
To find all meals containing pasta:

```
const unsigned int meal_count = weekly_meals.size();  
for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < meal_count; ++i)
{
    if (weekly_meals[i].contains_ingredient("pasta"))
    {
        // Process the pasta meal
    }
}
```

The above code is complete, but illustrates the concept of moving meal properties into a Meal and searching a container of meals for meals containing the appropriate attribute.

**Edit 1:  Properties as a Class**
You may want to make classifications as a class type.  For example, creating a pasta class:

```
class Pasta_Meal : public Meal
{
  public:  
    Pasta_Meal(const std::string& title, unsigned serving_size)
        : Meal(title, "pasta", serving_size)
    { ; }
};
```

The `Pasta_Meal` *is-a* `Meal` whose primary ingredient is pasta.
Example Usage:

```
Pasta_Meal spaghetti_meat_sauce("spaghetti and meatsauce", 6);
Pasta_Meal mac_and_cheese("mac and cheese", 4);
Pasta_Meal fettuccine_alfredo("fettucini alfredo", 8);
```

This is only one of many design ideas.

Use a design which simplifies your application, and makes implementation easier.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to have *index* tables, which contain the meal name and the attribute value:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>  meals_by_ingredient;
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> meals_by_serving_size;
```

You could have:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>  meals_by_ingredient =
{
    {"Goulash", "Pasta"},
    {"Tacos", "Ground Beef"},
    {"Mac&Cheese", "Pasta"},
};
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> meals_by_serving_size = 
{
    {"Goulash", 6},
    {"Tacos", 4},
    {"Mac&Cheese", 5},
};
```

In the above, there is one table for each attribute you want to access.  If you want to know the serving size for tacos, use:
`unsigned int serving_size = meals_by_serving_size["Tacos"];`